# Limiting number of decimal digits in ArcGIS to have exported file in CAD with same format?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, cad

I am supposed to have some numeric values in ARCGIS 10.2 with 3 decimals Digits and then convert them to Microstation or AutoCAD. I did this Setting using field calculator and 'round' function in arcgis but when I convert it to CAD again it would come with more than 10 decimals which is not desired.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do this is to add a field and specify float.  It will give you the option of setting a "Precision" and "Scale." Precision indicates total number of characters allowed in the field. Scale indicates total number of decimal places allowed. Set Precision to whatever it needs to be and set scale to 3.

Then, in field calculator use the expression:

"New field" =

[old field]

See this: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n0000001m000000